# NTP maxpoll limits

Tags: ntp

Regarding NTP's *maxpoll* configuration attribute, many resources state:

> The maximum poll interval defaults to 10 (1,024 s), but can be
>   increased by the maxpoll option to an upper limit of 17 (36.4 h)

However I couldn't find references for hacing it lower than the defaul value of 10 (1,024s). Can it be set for a lower value? say to 6?

Comment: You could just use Science and test it...

Comment: @mgorven - I'm trying to, haven't figured out how to validate it for sure with the monitoring app. besides, I believe in having stuff documented for the sake of others, and the stack exchange platform is ideal for that. If I will manage to find the answer, I will share of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the ntp.conf(5) man page, the lowest value of `maxpoll` is 4. This setting requires that `minpoll` is set to 3.

> **minpoll** minpoll, **maxpoll** maxpoll
>
> These options specify the minimum and maximum poll intervals for NTP messages, in seconds as a power of two.   The  maximum  poll interval  defaults  to 10 (1,024 s), but can be increased by the maxpoll option to an upper limit of 17 (36.4  h).   The  minimum poll  interval defaults to 6 (64 s), but can be decreased by the minpoll option to a lower limit of 4 (16 s).  These  option  are valid only with the server and peer commands.

Edit: This is how it is implemented in ntp-4.2.6p5/ntpdc/ntpdc_ops.c:1433:

```
if (minpoll < NTP_MINPOLL || minpoll > NTP_MAXPOLL ||
    maxpoll < NTP_MINPOLL || maxpoll > NTP_MAXPOLL ||
    minpoll > maxpoll) {
        fprintf(fp, "***min/max-poll must be within %d..%d\n",
                NTP_MINPOLL, NTP_MAXPOLL);
        res = TRUE;
}
```

Where NTP_MINPOLL is 3 and NTP_MAXPOLL is 17.

Comment: they are referring to `minpoll` not `maxpoll`. This is exactly the reason for my question

Comment: You can set `minpoll 3` and `maxpoll 4` if I understood that correctly.

Comment: Use the source, Luke.

Comment: Now you're talking! :)